# Как правильно реализовать получение ссылки на картинку из другого потока

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Делаю многопоточную программу-парсер для одного сайта, которая должна выводить оттуда новости с картинками.

Во время выполнения столкнулся с проблемой: если использовать метод `synchronized`, то программа работает некорректно(белый экран стоит до тех пор, пока персер не дойдёт до конца страницы, и лишь потом появляются элементы), а если без него, то программа неработает, ссылаясь на то, что ссылка на картинку равна `null`. Как правильно реализовать многопоточность? Код оставляю ниже:

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    public Elements content;
    //public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<NewsElement> newsList = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new NewThread().execute();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, newsList);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String cleaner(String a){
            String source = a;
            String result = "";
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
            arr.add(source);

            for(String retrival: source.split(" ")){
                arr.add(retrival);

            }
            arr.remove(0);
            Iterator<String> iterator = arr.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String string = iterator.next();
                if (string.equals("Россия") || string.equals("Екатеринбург")) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }else{
                    result += string+" ";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        String url_interpretator(String src){
            String result="";
            String interval = "";

            char[] morph = src.toCharArray();
            morph[0]=' ';
            morph[1]=' ';

            for (char a : morph){
                if(a==' '){
                    continue;
                }else{
                    interval=interval+a;
                }
            }

            result="https://"+interval;

            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected  String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            String  newsText,  newsDate,  newsTime,  newsPicURL,  newsLink;

            try{
                doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com/?&%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5").get();
                content = doc.select(".pub");

                int link_counter = 0;
               // titleList.clear();
                newsList.clear();
                for(Element contents: content){

                    //titleList.add(cleaner(contents.text()));





                    String linkID = doc.getElementsByClass("pub").get(link_counter).attr("href");
                    //Log.d("parse", linkID);
                    String region = doc.getElementsByClass("region").get(link_counter).text();
                    //Log.d("Title", region);
                    String time = doc.getElementsByTag("time").get(link_counter).attr("datetime");
                    //Log.d("Time", time);




//                   Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com"+href).get();
//                   String pic_url=url_interpretator(doc2.getElementsByTag("img").get(1).attr("src"));
//                   Log.d("picture", contents.text() +" "+ pic_url);
                    PicLoader pl = new PicLoader(linkID, contents);
                    pl.start();


                    DateAndTime dat = new DateAndTime(time);
                    newsText=cleaner(contents.text());
                    newsDate=dat.getYear()+" ";
                    newsTime=dat.getTime();
                    newsPicURL=pl.getURL();
                    Log.d("Hotline miami", newsPicURL);
                    newsLink="https://znak.com"+linkID;

                    NewsElement newsElement = new NewsElement( newsText,  newsDate,  newsTime,  newsPicURL,  newsLink);
                    newsList.add(newsElement);



                    link_counter++;
                }

            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public class PicLoader extends Thread{

            String href;
            Element contents;
            String readyURL="";


            public  PicLoader(String href, Element contents) {
                this.href = href;
                this.contents = contents;
            }



            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                synchronized (readyURL) {
                    super.run();
                    Document doc2 = null;
                    try {
                        doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com" + href).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String pic_url = url_interpretator(doc2.getElementsByTag("img").get(1).attr("src"));
                    readyURL = pic_url;
                    Log.d("picture", contents.text() + " " + pic_url);
                }
            }

            synchronized String getURL(){
                return readyURL;
            }
        }
    }

    private class DateAndTime{


        private String date;
        private String year;
        private String time="";
        private char[] timeArr;

        DateAndTime(String date){
            this.date=date;
        }

        String getYear(){


            String[] dateAndTime = date.split("T");
            String[] dateArr = dateAndTime[0].split("-");

            timeArr = dateAndTime[1].toCharArray();
            year = dateArr[2]+"."+dateArr[1]+"."+dateArr[0];

            return year;

        }


        String getTime(){

            for(int i = 0; i<timeArr.length-4; i++){
                time=time+timeArr[i];
            }

            String intTime = String.valueOf(timeArr[0])+String.valueOf(timeArr[1]);
            int timeValue = Integer.valueOf(intTime)+5;

            if(timeValue>23){
                timeValue=timeValue-24;
                String time = "0"+String.valueOf(timeValue)+timeArr[2]+timeArr[3]+timeArr[4];
                return time;
            }else{
                String time = String.valueOf(timeValue)+timeArr[2]+timeArr[3]+timeArr[4];
                return time;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**NewsElement.class**

```
public class NewsElement {
    String newsText;
    String newsDate;
    String newsTime;
    String newsPicURL;
    String newsLink;

    public NewsElement(String newsText, String newsDate, String newsTime, String newsPicURL, String newsLink) {
        this.newsText = newsText;
        this.newsDate = newsDate;
        this.newsTime = newsTime;
        this.newsPicURL = newsPicURL;
        this.newsLink = newsLink;
    }

    public String getNewsText() {
        return newsText;
    }

    public void setNewsText(String newsText) {
        this.newsText = newsText;
    }

    public String getNewsDate() {
        return newsDate;
    }

    public void setNewsDate(String newsDate) {
        this.newsDate = newsDate;
    }

    public String getNewsTime() {
        return newsTime;
    }

    public void setNewsTime(String newsTime) {
        this.newsTime = newsTime;
    }

    public String getNewsPicURL() {
        return newsPicURL;
    }

    public void setNewsPicURL(String newsPicURL) {
        this.newsPicURL = newsPicURL;
    }

    public String getNewsLink() {
        return newsLink;
    }

    public void setNewsLink(String newsLink) {
        this.newsLink = newsLink;
    }
}
```

**recycler_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/publish_newscard">

  <!--  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/publish_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/publis_title"
                android:text="sample text"
                android:textColor="@color/veryBlack"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/publish_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="21.12.2017 " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/publish_time"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10:43"
                    android:textColor="@color/znakColor"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```